# Custom middleware for express routes

Tags: javascript, express, middleware

I actually implemented a custom middleware in an expressJs application. I aim for modifying the request object before sending it back. It works and the result is exactly what i was expecting, but i am not sure if this is the correct way to do so. I am kind of afraid, that manipulating the `reqeust` object is not the correct way to do this.

Here is the code:

```
expressApp.get('/apps/:id', isAuthenticated, appLinks(dbController), async (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.__appLink)
})
```

**app-links.ts**:

```
export const appLinks: MiddlewareWrapper = (dbController: DatabaseHandler) => async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

  dbResult = modifyMyDatabaseResult(await dbController.getApps());
  req.__appLink = dbResult
  next()

}
```

As you can see, in my route i send `req.__appLink` which was set inside the middleware. It this the correct way to do such things?

Answer (score 1):

This is good! Nothing is wrong with modifying the req object.

Comment: This doesnt answer OPs question

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is fine. But for better presentation you can save the result of `req._appLink` in a variable and pass it to `res` object.